# config.secret_key_base error on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following Hartl's Rails tutorial and ran into this error when trying to open `http://localhost:3000/` after running `rails s`. I tried open a rails server with my default setup and it works fine, so I'm suspecting that the error comes form the following `Gemfile` that he specifies in the book. Is there something in here that should cause the problem?

My default setup is `ruby 2.0.0`, `rails 4.1.0`, `heroku-toolbelt/3.6.0 (x86_64-linux) ruby/1.9.3`.

[Hartl's `Gemfile`](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/demo_app#code-demo_gemfile_sqlite_version_redux) is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: The error is `You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into the same problem while following Hartl, and I think what's happening is this:

When you create an application with `rails new sample_app`, you're defaulting to the version you have installed: 4.1.
Rails 4.1 handles `config.secret_key_base` using a `secrets.yml` file; 4.0 uses `secret_token.rb`.
Because Hartl's Gemfile specifies Rails 4.0.5, when you run your application it looks for the latter file.

You could modify Hartl's Gemfile to specify Rails 4.1.0 (that's the route I chose); or you could copy Hartl's secret_token.rb from https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/config/initializers/secret_token.rb .

You could also use Hartl's version of Rails when you create the app, by using `rails _4.0.5_ new sample_app`. This will create a 4.0 app complete with `secret_token.rb`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I figured out the solution on my own and this is it. It's best to do all the installation like Hartl recommends